# single row subquery returns more than one row . what went wrong here?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with choice  as 
   (select level as dow,trunc(sysdate ,'D') - level as days
      from dual
      connect by level <=10
   ) 
select 
   (select count(*) from man,choice 
     where man_status='ACCEPTED'
     and  man_date_pub=choice.days 
     group by man_date_pub) as accepted,
   (select count(*) from man,choice 
     where man_status='SUBMITTED' 
     and man_date_sub=choice.days 
     group by man_date_sub) as submitted,
   (select count(*) from man,choice
     where man_status='CREATED' 
     and man_date_created=choice.days
     group by man_date_created) as created,
     choice.days
from choice 
order by days;
```

This gives me this error :

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Answer (score 1):

Scalar cursors must return one row. Your sub-queries don't do that, because there are hits on multiple days. This approach might solve it:

```
with choice as 
            (select trunc(sysdate, 'D' ) - level as days
                from dual
                connect by level <=10
         ) 
select 
      sum(case when man_status='ACCEPTED' and man_date_pub=choice.days then 1 else 0 end)  as accepted,
      sum(case when man_status='SUBMITTED' and man_date_sub=choice.days then 1 else 0 end)  as submitted,
      sum(case when man_status='CREATED' and man_date_created=choice.days then 1 else 0 end)  as created,
      choice.days
from choice
      left join man
         on (man_date_pub = choice.days
             or man_date_sub = choice.days
             or man_date_created = choice.days)
group by choice.days
order by choice.days
/
```

Comment: That's not a very informative comment. Please explain how it's not working. Please note that I have changed my code, having invested the time to create the test data you didn't bother to post.

Comment: sorry man.the problem here is its going in infinite loop.i am trying to modify the query you provided then i will show you the  result.

Comment: 187 0 0 31-MAR-16
99 0 0 01-APR-16
100 0 0 02-APR-16
5 0 0 03-APR-16
28 0 0 04-APR-16

this is how it is giving result. where submitted and created field is always 0

Comment: Apparently you're running a modified version of my query against a data set which you haven't published. So I'm not sure what you're expecting me to do. I have given you a query which I think matches your stated requirements, and which works on my own set of test data. If it's not working for you, please post the actual code you're running and some sample data to reproduce the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

It may cause of your group by clause try to remove  group by clause  and check 
Like:

`with choice  as 
            (select level as dow,trunc(sysdate ,'D') - level as days
from dual
connect by level <=10
         ) 
select 
  (select count(*) from man,choice where man_status='ACCEPTED' and man_date_pub=choice.days) as accepted,
  (select count(*) from man,choice where man_status='SUBMITTED' and man_date_sub=choice.days) as submitted,
  (select count(*) from man,choice where man_status='CREATED' and man_date_created=choice.days) as created,
 choice.days
 from choice order by days;`

Comment: no the result i am getting from this query is not as expected